# Cast IQueryable to a simple object

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I try to use a `IValueConverter` in a hospital management system prototype to show doctor's surname instead of his o her id. It converts value of list view with patient object's data including doctor's id.

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
 {
        using (var db = new MainEntityModel())
        {
            user doctor = (from d in db.users where d.user_id == (int)value select d).Cast<user>();
            string DoctorName = doctor.surname;
            return DoctorName;
        }
 }
```

I couldn't handle it. My query returns `IQueryable` with one doctor type object and I can't use it like an object with specific properties. I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyApp.user>' to 'MyApp.user'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Another approach also failed:

```
 using (var db = new MainEntityModel())
 {
     var doctor = from d in db.users 
                  where d.user_id == (int)value 
                  select d;

     string DoctorName = doctor.surname;

     return DoctorName;
}
```

I've got an error on the line assigning the `DoctorName`:

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'surname' and no accessible extension method 'surname' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried a lot of approaches (creating constructor, initializing new user with query data) and asking for help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.Where()` clause use `FirstOrDefault()`, this will give you object of `user` class.

```
 using System.Linq;
 ...
 using (var db = new MainEntityModel())
    {
         string DoctorName = db.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.user_id == (int)value)?.surname;
         return DoctorName;
    }
```